# Paypal Standard Order Status Shows Pending Payment

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, upgrade, order-status

I have upgraded Magento from ver 1.4 to 1.7.0.2. I have placed order successfully from Paypal Standard but order status still show Pending Payment.

I am facing the following issues:

Order status showing Pending Payment. 
Orders that have pending payment status not displayed in member account. 
No order confirmation email send to customer. other email are working fine on site.

I have found so many questions related to this no clue work for me. Please Help !!

Please Help !!

Comment: i am not getting email from paypal, all links in answers are not working. can you please tell what you did to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the IPN callback is not reaching your site (or working) after the upgrade.

Some things to check:

1. In paypal, what does the IPN callback history say. (in paypal, select 'History->IPN history') Any errors reported there? This may tell you where the issue is.
2. In paypal, do you have a ipn callback url set, and what is it. (not really needed, as magento passes the url, but still good to check, just in case)

ref: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/paypal_standard_payments_setup_with_ipn

> Starting with Magento 1.4.0.0, the ipn url is now :
>   http://www.yoursite.com/paypal/ipn/standard/, however since 1.4.1.0 it
>   changed again to be just http://www.yoursite.com/paypal/ipn/

Inchoo has written a great article on how to debug IPN callbacks: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/debugging-paypal-ipn-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks Proxiblue .. I have checked IPN history in paypal and it seems that IPN url is related to old Magento Verison. how can i change this from code ?

Comment: Hi, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078049/magento-paypal-ipn-configuration

ARe you sure your upgrade was good? Sounds like possibly you have files that did not upgrade. Possible the files may be located in /app/code/local/Mage (thus would not upgrade) ?

Comment: Also see comment from this thread: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/196048/

"On my upgrade to 1.4.1.0, SOME of my PayPal information was present in the Admin Config. area.
In particular, I noticed that the API fields had security star / asterisk content. “*******”
However, I had to re-enter my actual API information in those fields.  They were either incorrect, or merely placeholders, not my actual correct API information."

Comment: There was files in local realted to Magento 1.4 that one of my collegue copy form old site to new site. Thanks alot

Comment: Why were they copied? You will need to diff those files to the core files of your original magento version (1.4), and determine what was chnaged in them, and re-implement the changes (if needed) - better to implement proper modules and not copy files to /app/code/local/mage (really to be avoided)

Comment: Yes I have removed all the files and checking the files about modification. Once Again Many thanks :)