# Paypal Standard Order Status Shows Pending Payment paid payment

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-standard

recently I changed **Email Associated with PayPal Merchant Account**  since that i am facing an issue.
  order status **pending payment** however customer paid payment with paypal
i am using **System->Configuration->Payment Methods->PayPal Standard**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Try Below Links to overcomes this Problem:

http://www.kgntechnologies.com/order-status-shown-pending-payment-magento-backend-even-paid-paypal-find-solution/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252427/magento-1-7-0-2-pending-payment-status-after-successful-payment-in-paypal

[Paypal Standard Order Status Shows Pending Payment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/paypal-standard-order-status-shows-pending-payment)